# Javascript - Difference between function declarations

Tags: javascript, scope, execution

I've just started developing in Javascript, and have been reading up on scope and execution context. I was wondering if there's a difference between this:

```
function fun1 () {
    var x = 1;

    function fun2 () {
         x = x*2;
         alert(x);
    }
}
```

and:

```
function fun1 () {
    var x = 1;
    fun2(x);
}

function fun2 (x) {
    x = x*2;
    alert(x);
}
```

Would there be reasons to use one over the other? Do they have any performance/security implications (or other unexpected implications for beginner JS developers)?

Comment: Well … it is impossible to call `fun2` in the first example.

Comment: Second example is better for re-usability. Now you can call function **fun2** again in other functions.

Comment: @Quentin Impossible from outside `fun1`, inside it's not.

Comment: @Arg0n — It *isn't* called from inside `fun1`

Comment: What you do in the first case is an example of closure. Read about JavaScript closures and you should be clear about it

Comment: @Quentin Still not impossible to add the call inside. Code is usually modifiable. He does not need to put it outsite `fun1` to be able to call it as you state. With your logic `fun1` is impossible to call, since he does not call it with the shown code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we talk about your first approach, it is not possible to call `fun2` because you have enclosed it within `fun1` and its scope is local. However you can ammend your `fun1` to call `fun2` as follows:

```
 var fun1 = (function(){

    var x = 1;

    var fun2 = function(){
         x = x*2;
         alert(x);
    };

    return {
      fun2: fun2
    }

 })();
```

The above return statement will make your `fun2` as `public` scope that you can call it with the `fun1` object as follows:

```
  fun1.fun2();
```

> Please note that the `x` variable is private and only accessible within `fun1` function. If you need to access it using `fun1.x`, you will have to return it in your `fun1` as I've returned `fun2`.

This is called `modular or enclosed pattern`. By this we can achieve encapsulation.

IF we talk about your second approach i.e pretty simple, your `fun1` will call `fun2` . I hope, it clears the concept.

Answer (score 2):

The main difference is that at the first case `fun2` will be available only in the `fun1` scope. At the second case both functions will be available at scope, where their definition is

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript scope is defined by the enclosing function. That is, code defined within a function is not visible outside the function.

So, in your 1st example, `func2` in defined inside `func1`, and thus is visible *only* inside `func1`.

In your 2nd example, it is defined in the global scope (the `window` object, when running in a browser), and as such is callable from anywhere, just like `func1`.